# Types of input for get_logger in ros2 RCLCPP_INFO

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was trying to find what types of input can be provided for

> RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "data: %*", data)

I had used `%s` for string kind of output but was wondering if it can take any other types of data. While looking over some codes I saw the use of `%g` not sure what it represents.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399050/types-of-input-for-get_logger-in-ros2-rclcpp_info/) by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2022-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The second argument in the logging macros is a format specification, i.e. a pointer to a null-terminated multibyte string specifying how to interpret the data. As such, you can use any standard format specifier accepted by `printf`. Here's a small reference list: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Also, from the same link: `%g` converts floating-point number to decimal or decimal exponent notation depending on the value and the precision.

---

Originally posted by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) with karma: 456 on 2022-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2022-04-15**:
Can I know which second argument you are talking about?

**Comment by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) on 2022-04-15**:
In `RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "data: %s", "message")` the `"data: %s"` const character buffer would correspond to the second argument.